# How do I calculate average duration in Google Sheets Result from years:months:day

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-arrayformula, google-sheets-dates

All I'm trying to do is to get an Average Duration to result in Google Sheets to the average duration from a set of duration `years:months:days`

[image]

I calculate DURATION using this formula:

```
=INT((K3-B3)/365)&" Years, "&INT(MOD((K3-B3),365)/30)&" Months, "&ROUND(MOD((MOD((K3-B3),365)),30),0)&" Days"
```

However, I cannot Average the total duration using Google Sheets standard average formula.

Comment: next time share a copy of your sheet!

Answer (score 1):

### TOTAL:

```
=INT((SUM(ARRAYFORMULA(M1:M14-L1:L14)))/365)&" Years, "&
 INT(MOD((SUM(ARRAYFORMULA(M1:M14-L1:L14))),365)/30)&" Months, "&
 ROUND(MOD((MOD((SUM(ARRAYFORMULA(M1:M14-L1:L14))),365)),30),0)&" Days"
```

### AVERAGE:

```
=INT((AVERAGE(ARRAYFORMULA(M1:M14-L1:L14)))/365)&" Years, "&
 INT(MOD((AVERAGE(ARRAYFORMULA(M1:M14-L1:L14))),365)/30)&" Months, "&
 ROUND(MOD((MOD((AVERAGE(ARRAYFORMULA(M1:M14-L1:L14))),365)),30),0)&" Days"
```

[image]

Comment: @ZakiFalimbany https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers